# How does TLS Channel ID guarantee client authenticity?

Tags: authentication, ssl

I've read [RFC draft](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-balfanz-tls-channelid-00) for Channel ID. I've also read the earlier [draft for OBC's](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-balfanz-tls-obc-01), but I'm a little slow to follow. I understand that Google has implemented a new extension based on their earlier Channel ID work. I'm curious to learn what the benefits are and how they are accomplished, but I can't seem to find much detail on the topic from a systems perspective (I'm not a crypto man).

How does Channel ID guarantee the authenticity of a client machine in a SSL session?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Channel ID do not guarantee authenticity, but provides traceability.
It is based on a key pair generated for a specific domain, which is stored on the client, and reused for subsequent TLS connections. An application is then able to associate this Channel ID to a user session, and make sure this session is only used with this Channel ID.
Channel ID is thus a mean to track (for the sake of security) a given client, making it possible to ensure that an application session is not stolen and reused elsewhere.